# Python: creating a class instance via static method vs class method

Tags: python, oop, static-methods, class-method

Let's say I have a class and would like to implement a method which creates an instance of that class. What I have is 2 options:

1. static method,
2. class method.

An example:

```
class DummyClass:
    def __init__(self, json):
        self.dict = json
    
    @staticmethod
    def from_json_static(json):
        return DummyClass(json)

    @classmethod
    def from_json_class(cls, json):
        return cls(json)
```

Both of the methods work:

```
dummy_dict = {"dummy_var": 124}
dummy_instance = DummyClass({"test": "abc"})

dummy_instance_from_static = dummy_instance.from_json_static(dummy_dict)
print(dummy_instance_from_static.dict)
> {'dummy_var': 124}

dummy_instance_from_class = DummyClass.from_json_class(dummy_dict)
print(dummy_instance_from_class.dict)
> {'dummy_var': 124}
```

What I often see in codes of other people is the `classmethod` design instead of `staticmethod`. Why is this the case?

Or, rephrasing the question to possibly get a more comprehensive answer: what are the pros and cons of creating a class instance via `classmethod` vs `staticmethod` in Python?

Comment: The `@classmethod` approach creates an object of the right type if invoked on a subclass, rather than on `DummyClass` itself.  If you know there will never be any subclasses, you might as well use `@staticmethod`.

Comment: just a question, what is the usecase of creating class instance in same class via two methods?

Comment: @sahasrara62 it was just an illustrative example

Answer (score 3):

Two big advantages of the `@classmethod` approach:

First, you don't hard-code the name. Given modern refactoring tools in IDEs, this isn't as big of a deal, but it is nice to not have your code break if you change the name of your `Foo`, class to `Bar`::

```
class Bar:
    @statmicmethod
    def make_me():
        return Foo()
```

Another advantage (at least, you should understand the difference!) is how this behaves with inheritance:

```
class Foo:

    @classmethod
    def make_me_cm(cls):
        return cls()

    @staticmethod
    def make_me_sm():
        return Foo()

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

print(Bar.make_me_cm()) # it's a Bar instance
print(Bar.make_me_sm()) # it's a Foo instance
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm trying to work out what's exactly the advantage in your second argument. Is it that the inheritance behaves "as expected", i.e. creating and instance of `Bar` instead of `Foo`?